# Can new branches be grafted to cedar hedge stump?

Tags: trees, pruning, hedge, grafting, cedar

I have a large cedar hedge that in most parts is very full and dense, but due to excessive outward growth and lack of consistent pruning, there are sections that are very open and "woody", with the stump exposed and not a whole lot of branches for new growth.

I've read that with cedar trees, old wood will not put out new growth, and as such, I'm concerned that this section of the hedge will not fill in well, given the lack of existing growth in the area.

I was wondering, is it possible to graft new small branches to the stump? If so, which grafting technique would be the most effective here?

Comment: I have never heard of grafting a conifer  but I can't say it is impossible . It is common for deciduous trees to sprout from a stump, but I never heard of a conifer doing it.

Comment: Ohhhhhh this is interesting. There have been so many times when this would have been useful to do. I hope this is possible. Is there a name for this technique?

Comment: I have seen videos of people grafting conifers, I just wonder if a graft on an old wood stump would take.